# MathJax, my code doesn't seem to work completely fine, can anybody have a look?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I'm having some weird problem with MathJax. Everything on my site works fine, every MathJax snippet, except some subpage. I'm making a website about functions and their transformations in Polish.
When I'm trying to perform the code, it's like it breaks performing in the middle.
I'm attaching a link to the image with the code and the results: [image: http://s11.postimg.org/d9nrfiw8z/Bez_tytu_u3.png]
I'm sure I've checked the code in detail... It's really important for me to work fine!
Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
Funkcja $f(k*x)$ rozciąga się w poziomie dla $k>1 \lor k<-1$, zaś dla $ 1<k \land k<-1 $ jest ona ściśnięta w poziomie.
Funkcja $k*f(x)$ ściska się w pionie dla $k>1 \lor k<-1$, zaś dla $ 1<k \land k<-1$ jest ona rozciągnięta w pionie.
Warto zaznaczyć, iż gdy $k$ jest ujemne, to funkcja dodatkowo obraca się symetrycznie wokół osi OX dla $k*f(x)$ i wokół osi OY dla $f(k*x)$.
```

Oh, now I got it... The code was broken in the same place where "1< k" is placed, and Firefox reads is as a HTML tag, and this made the MathJax code run not properly.
Question can be closed

Comment: Please post the code IN YOUR QUESTION, not in an image.

Comment: I forgot to say that when I put my code into pre tags, it was cut (I could see only a part of it), so I've decided to put it into an image...

Comment: Paste the code into the textbox, select all of it, and click the `{}` button on the editor. This will format your code so it will show correctly. Do not wrap `<pre>`, `<code>` or any other markup around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the browser processing the (unescaped) `<` (which makes the HTML invalid) before MathJax gets to it.

Long story short, try `$k &gt; 1 \lor k&lt;-1$` to be safe.